# Problem with export DXF - Why?

Tags: export

**Export do dxf doesn't work - why..?**

File:
https://we.tl/t-alrsR9t9rT

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution entails:

- converting to grease pencil
- and again - convert to mesh

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i will try make this more useful in this week!